# Getting XCode to report a test case failure in a calling class

Tags: xcode, sentestingkit

If I write a helper method for test case:

```
- (void)testCallsHelper
{
    [self helper]; // Can I get Xcode to highlight the failure here?
}

- (void)helper
{
    STFail(@"Fail"); // Xcode highlights failure here
}
```

This would be handy because it's quicker to use Xcode highlighting to jump to where an error is occurring and its also handy to put repeated code into helper method.

Comment: Aside from, of course, putting all the assertions in the caller.